# Count consecutive ones in a binary list

Tags: python, programming-challenge

There is a list consisting of zeroes and ones. I want to find out the length of the longest streak of ones. Is there a better solution?

```
def consecutive_one(data):
   one_list = []
   size = 0
   for num in data:
       if num == 1:
           one_list.append(num)
       elif num == 0 and size < len(one_list):
           size = len(one_list)
           one_list = []

    return size

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
    print(consecutive_one(data))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both your and janos' implementations are broken:

```
data = [1, 0] * 10000
consecutive_one(data)
#>>> 140
```

This is because you don't always reset after seeing a 0. Going from janos', you should have

```
longest = 0
current = 0
for num in data:
    if num == 1:
        current += 1
    else:
        longest = max(longest, current)
        current = 0

return max(longest, current)
```

and equivalent for the original.

You'll find that this functionality is largely provided by `itertools.groupby`, though:

```
from itertools import groupby

def len_iter(items):
    return sum(1 for _ in items)

def consecutive_one(data):
    return max(len_iter(run) for val, run in groupby(data) if val)
```

Answer (score 8):

#### You have a bug

If the last value is a 1, and it is the end of the longest consecutive sequence, it won't be taken into account.
The fix is to change the return statement to this:

```
return max(size, len(one_list))
```

#### Unnecessary condition

If you *know* your input only contains 0 and 1 values,
then you can simplify this condition:

> ```
> if num == 1:
>     # ...
> elif num == 0 and size < len(one_list):
>     # ...
> ```

By dropping the `num == 0`:

> ```
> if num == 1:
>     # ...
> elif size < len(one_list):
>     # ...
> ```

*But note that this is not good enough, as there's still a bug hiding there as @veedrac explains in his answer, instead of an `elif`, this should be rewritten using an `else`.*

#### Improving storage efficiency

There's no need to store the 1s as you count them.
You can just keep the count in a variable.

#### Testing

Instead of running your function using test data,
give a try to doctests, like this:

```
def consecutive_one(data):
    """
    >>> consecutive_one([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
    2
    >>> consecutive_one([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])
    3
    >>> consecutive_one([0, 1] * 10)
    1
    """
    # ... the implementation ...
```

To run all doctests within a file, run `python -m doctest yourfile.py`.
When all tests pass, there is no output.
When something fails you will get a detailed report.
This is an excellent way to test your implementation,
and also to document usage with examples and expected outputs.

Comment: Just to be more precise, he doesn't have to know that the list contains only `0` and `1`. The purpose is to count every `1`, so it's not really relevant if it's `0` or another character, as long as it's not `1`.

Answer (score 0):

**You have a bug on elif statement `size < len(one_list):`**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())       

    binary = [int(x) for x in bin(n)[2:]]  

    one_list = []
    size = 0

    for num in binary:
        if num == 1:
            one_list.append(num)

            if size < len(one_list):
                size = len(one_list)

        elif num == 0 :
            one_list.clear()

    print(size)
```

Comment: (Welcome to Code Review!) (While valid, this has been [stated before](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/138583).)